# svn merge trunk into a branch for which I've lost the logs

Tags: svn

Is it possible to merge trunk into a branch which hasn't any logs, actually trunk hasn't any log records as some bonehead lost all logs after removing and then recreated both trunk and branch ? What's the proper and safe way to do this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could merge with `--ignore-ancestry` Some good info here: [Advanced Merging](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html#svn.branchmerge.advanced.ancestry).

Comment: Not sure what's wrong but I still see some files marked with C though I've used "--ignore-ancestry".

Comment: Then you need to resolve the conflicts by keeping one side or the other or manually integrating them.